# Set Default Value of Column Equal to PK of inserted record, and use it as Foreign Key Reference

Tags: mariadb, foreign-key, primary-key, relational-theory, mariadb-10.3

I'm using MariaDB 10.3, and what I'm trying to do is an establishment of a 1-to-n relationship as for example specified [here](https://blog.devart.com/types-of-relationships-in-sql-server-database.html) in the section "One-To-Many-Relationship". I'm trying to do so via:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  test_value INT NOT NULL DEFAULT ID
);

CREATE TABLE related_table (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  message VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'hello',
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES test_table(test_value)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

The SQL Fiddle Editor etc. fail at the execution of this, with the Error:

`Function or expression 'AUTO_INCREMENT' cannot be used in the DEFAULT clause of 'ID'`

So I suppose you cannot set the default value of a column equal to another column, if the value of that other column is defined by a function or an expression?

If I then omit the `AUTO_INCREMENT`, I get:

```
Can't create table "fiddle"."related_table" (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

So I assume you cannot create FOREIGN KEY constraints based on referenced columns with a default value?

Do you see another possibility to do what I need, which is:

A) When I insert a new record into `test_table` and do not provide `test_value`, its value should be equal to the primary key of the inserted record, which should be auto-generated.

B) The `related_table`'s `ID` should refer to the `test_table`'s `test_value` as foreign key.

The only workaround I currently see is to:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  test_value INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE related_table (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  message VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'hello',
  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES test_table(test_value)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

And then, if I insert for example 3 records into `test_table`:

1. Insert first new record into `test_table`, and grab the `LAST_INSERT_ID`.
2. Update the first record just created by setting the value of `test_value` of it equal to that returned `LAST_INSERT_ID`.
3. Insert the two remaining records into `test_table`, this time directly with the `LAST_INSERT_ID` returned from before as the value of `test_value`.
4. Insert new record into `related_table` with the value of the returned `LAST_INSERT_ID` as its primary key `ID` field.

But this seems overcomplicated. Isn't there a better solution for this usecase?

Comment: FKs, DEFAULTs, etc, have significant limitations.  SQL is not a full programming language.  See if a `TRIGGER` will help you implement what you want.  If not, you are stuck with using app code or reformulating to use Stored routines.

Comment: Problem is that SQL triggers act on all rows on the concerned table, so I don‘t see how to use a trigger to act on the first inserted row of an execution set only, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 3-row example, redesign thus:

- Have 2 tables
- One table has one row per clump and provides the auto_increment
- The other table has the 3 rows
- Then build a transaction to do all the steps:

  ```
  BEGIN;
  INSERT INTO table1 ...;
  get $id from the LAST_INSERT_ID()
  foreach ...   -- walk through the 3 things
      INSERT INTO table2
          (..., test_value, ...)
          VALUES (..., $id, ...);
  COMMIT;
  ```

Think through which columns 'belong' in one table versus the other table.  You will probably find the end result is cleaner than the design you hypothecated.

Comment: Thanks for that, sir! The only complication is that the auto_incremented PK generated must be the FK from table_2, referencing table_1. And to my understanding, I cannot insert the record into table 1 first, as it needs to have an ID to refer to from table 1 upon insert. No? I‘ll test a solution anf will post it later if it works properly.

Comment: Well it seems my table creations already fail actually. When I run the last statements posted in my question; I get: `#1005 - Cannot create table (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`; any idea?

Comment: Looks like the problem was due to the fact that I did not index the `test_value` field in the query. At least when I did index it, I could set the FOREIGN KEY without any problem. Didn't MariaDB automatically index fields referenced by foreign keys?

Comment: Err 150 -- Either do the other CREATE first; or add the FKs after both CREATEsa are in place.

Comment: As for the PKs -- please explain the purpose of the PKs, why they need to be auto_inc, etc.

Comment: The error 150 seemed really to be due to the fact of the column to which the fk referred to wasn‘t an index, only that made things work (I tried what you‘ve said too), but thx for that too!

Comment: As for your other hint / needed details; I guess it makes sense to [continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141396/room-for-develjoe-and-rick-james), if you don't mind?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!